# $\sqrt{\frac{15}{11}}$ continued fraction

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know how to find a continued fraction representation of rationals and quadratic irrationals, but I'm not sure how to proceed with square roots of rationals. For example, I want to know how to get:
$$ \sqrt{\frac{15}{11}} = [1; \overline{5, 1, 24, 1, 5, 2}]$$

Any hints or guidelines?

Comment: Are you looking for a different answer than the *just sort of do it* answer?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: There's a general way of getting any continued fraction, which is really just an exercise in pulling out an algebra stick and hitting the problem hard enough.

Comment: You mean simply $a_{i+1} = 1/(\alpha_i - a_i)$ and then grind grind grind?

Comment: Yes. It's doable - I verified the first 4 steps by hand, and it's doable but boring. It's much easier if you're allowed a calculator. And it's downright short if you're allowed something with a floor function.

Comment: [Wikipedia to the rescue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Continued_fraction_expansion).

Comment: Yeah, that's certainly doable, but I was wondering if there exists a more elegant way which could also guarantee that I've hit upon a periodical sequence.

Comment: @Lucian Isn't that for quadratic irrationals? P.S. Never mind, I see my error, it's silly :D I'll write an answer now.

Comment: Yes, there is a more elegant method that guarantees that you have hit upon a periodic sequence.

Comment: Yes, I know about that method, I was wondering if it exists for square roots of rationals, not just quadratic irrationals. But of course, I was talking nonsense, as I pointed out in my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original poster here. I just want to say that I had a good laugh at myself because for some reason I thought $\sqrt{\frac{15}{11}}$ wasn't a quadratic irrational.

$$\sqrt{\frac{15}{11}}= \sqrt{\frac{15}{11}} \frac{\sqrt{11}}{\sqrt{11}} = \frac{\sqrt{165}}{11}$$

I'll say no more, I'd better go facepalm myself hard :)

**P.S.**
Just for the record, if anyone is wondering how to expand quadratic irrationals into continued fractions, it's all [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Continued_fraction_expansion), as Lucian already pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

Ummmm. If you do this as just a continued fraction, you have two problems, one is decimal accuracy being exceeded, the other is recognizing when the cycle is repeating. Nobody seems very happy about this method, but anyway: Gauss and Lagrange used a method for "quadratic irrationals" that avoids both problems. The downside is that you wind up dealing only with numbers that have a purely periodic continued fraction, so you need to relate to the original.

I included a brief description of the Gauss-Lagrange method in the middle of [BLOOOOOOOOOOOOOGGG](http://math.blogoverflow.com/2014/08/23/binary-quadratic-forms-over-the-rational-integers-and-class-numbers-of-quadratic-%EF%AC%81elds/?cb=1)

The number discussed below is $$  \frac{11 + \sqrt {165}}{4}  $$
Note that the absolute values of the "deltas" are your 5,1,24,1,5,2.

```
=========================================
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./indefCycle  -11  22  4

  0  form            -11          22           4


           1           0
           0           1

To Return  
           1           0
           0           1

0  form   -11 22 4   delta  5
1  form   4 18 -21   delta  -1
2  form   -21 24 1   delta  24
3  form   1 24 -21   delta  -1
4  form   -21 18 4   delta  5
5  form   4 22 -11   delta  -2
6  form   -11 22 4


  form   -11 x^2  + 22 x y  4 y^2 

minimum was   1rep   x = 1   y = -6 disc   660 dSqrt 25.690465157  M_Ratio  5.454545
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
-155  336
924  -2003
=========================================
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$
```

-------------------------===============----------

out of various ways to get from 15/11 to this thing,

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ 
    jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./indefCycle   15 0 -11 

  0  form             15           0         -11  delta     -1
  1  form            -11          22           4


           0          -1
           1          -1

To Return  
          -1           1
          -1           0

0  form   -11 22 4   delta  5
1  form   4 18 -21   delta  -1
2  form   -21 24 1   delta  24
3  form   1 24 -21   delta  -1
4  form   -21 18 4   delta  5
5  form   4 22 -11   delta  -2
6  form   -11 22 4


  form   -11 x^2  + 22 x y  4 y^2 

minimum was   1rep   x = 1   y = -6 disc   660 dSqrt 25.690465157  M_Ratio  5.454545
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
-155  336
924  -2003
=========================================
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$
```

========-------------==========------------------=========